# Minimalist CreateWindowEx fails

Tags: c++, winapi

this is just a minimalist console application that should show a windows created on the fly :

```
#include <windows.h>

void main()

     {
        WNDCLASSEX  _c4w = {0};

           _c4w.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
           //_c4w.hCursor       = ::LoadCursor(0, IDC_APPLICATION);
           //_c4w.hIcon         = ::LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
           _c4w.hInstance     = 0;
           _c4w.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
           _c4w.lpszClassName = "c4w";

        HWND _h;
        
        if(!::RegisterClassEx(&_c4w))

            { _h = ::CreateWindowEx( 0, "c4w",
                          "Minimal Windows Application",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
                          0, 0, 640, 480,
                          HWND_DESKTOP,
                          0,
                          ::GetModuleHandle(0), NULL
                        );

               ::ShowWindow(_h, SW_SHOW);
            }
     ....
    }
```

unfortunatlity the RegisterClassEx function actually always fails...

I am using C++ Builder 5 and compiling a console Application optioned as MultiThreaded but no VCL...

Comment: Your window class doesn't have a wndproc. And since RegisterClassEx returns a zero-atom on *failure*, why you're only attempting to create your window when you know the class registration failed is backwards. You already know it won't work (because you already know class-reg failed).

Comment: If you really want to use the Windows API, I suggest to use examples that already exist and work properly and using them as a starting point.  Trying to write Windows API programs by guessing or what you feel is correct is not the way to learn such a complex API.  Simple things such as returning the wrong values from a window procedure can be the difference between a working program and a non-working program.  Better yet, invest in books dedicated to Windows API programming, such as the ones written by Petzold.

Comment: @WhozCraig Don't use comments to answer questions. This should be posted as an answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the wndproc answer...I will give a try and come back...

Comment: What do you think will happen when you make `HWND_DESKTOP` be the parent? What are you trying to achieve with that? The documentation for `RegisterClassEx` says "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError." You really should do what it tells you to do.

Comment: I have ben told that the predfined constant HWND_DESKTOP should be used if creating standalone windows from a console application....  I also tried with common value 0 (zero for NULL)... same result (RegisterEx fails).... I also tried with a minimal WndProc ... No way, Registering fails...

Answer (score 1):

As @WhozCraig said Your window class doesn't have a wndproc. If you want to use winapi well, please study according to the official documentation. Your program needs a wndproc.

Here is [how to create a blank window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) in MSDN.

> Notice that the program does not explicitly call the WindowProc
> function, even though we said this is where most of the application
> logic is defined. Windows communicates with your program by passing it
> a series of messages.

In the code, `wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc` specifies the process callback function.

Comment: I fully understand your comment and aggree with it.... My question should be precised : from a console application (C++ Builder 5), that is with a main(...) function, where will I put the WinMain(...) subsequents calls ?

Comment: The console can call winapi normally, but a normal win32 desktop program needs to be preprocessed, which the console program cannot do. I recommend that you use Microsoft's official tools for development.

Comment: see the answer I post below

Comment: See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program

Comment: Very interressant to copy and paste that pretty code into a C++ Builder 5.0, but I cannot create a suitable final output... Compiler says "_main is not defined." ! Any compiler option I have by passed ?

Comment: I fully aggree with you : in case of pure Windows applications, we should use Microsoft IDEs... But I really have in mind to cover other systems...

Answer (score 0):

I understood that a normal Win32 application using HWND and WNDPROC is not what I have done, but here is my solution :

```
HWND GetSTD()

 { static
   HWND     _result(0);
   static
   bool     _lock(false);
   static
   bool     _setup(false);

   while(_lock) ::Sleep(0);

   if(_setup == false)
     { _lock = true;

       OSVERSIONINFO _os;

       _os.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
       ::GetVersionEx(&_os);

       if(_os.dwPlatformId != VER_PLATFORM_WIN32s)
         { char _title[1024];

           ::GetConsoleTitle(_title, sizeof(_title));

           _result = ::FindWindow(0, _title);

           if(_os.dwPlatformId == VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS)
             { _result = ::GetWindow(_result, GW_CHILD);

               if(_result != 0)
                 { char _class[128];

                   ::GetClassName(_result, _class, sizeof(_class));

                   while(::strcmp(_class, "ttyGrab") != 0)
                        { _result = ::GetNextWindow(_result, GW_HWNDNEXT);

                          if(_result != 0)
                            ::GetClassName(_result, _class, sizeof(_class));
                        }
                 }
             }
         }

       _setup = true;
       _lock = false;
     }

   return _result;
 }
```

Using the resulting HWND, we could draw over the console with the ::GetDC() and ::ReleaseDC() mechanism...

NB : static variables are used to ensure to return only 1 STD handle per call...

Comment: Does `CreateWindowEx` work properly?

Comment: Just can't try it as I cannot produce a Win32 Simple application with C++Builder5.0....

Comment: Does this solve your original question? Minimalist CreateWindowE?

Comment: I just googled for creating a Win32 application using c++Builder5, and found that if I do not check the Console Application checkbox, then I can define the WinMain function.... So that answered the question, and not... My goal was to start FROM a console application and opening multiple child sub windows... What I can do is start from a Win32 window and open sub consoles windows... lol

Comment: So CreateWindowEx doesnt work for me....  May be you can tell me how to create and open a Graphical Window as a child of a Console ?